# How to loop through all DevExpress Textbox controls

Tags: c#, javascript, devexpress

Hi I have a need to loop through all devexpress textbox controls and trim textbox values in javascript. Is there a way to to do this. I need to trim textbox controls on LostFocus or submit events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DevExpress client side functionality. [Here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientControl_GetControlCollectiontopic) you can find out how to get all controls on the page. [ASPxClientTextBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientTextBoxtopic) should help to solve the problem too.  Do not forget enable ClientSideApi for the each TextBox